# apache beam inverse operation of util.BatchElements

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

What is the inverse operation of [apache_beam.transforms.util.BatchElements](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.transforms.util.html#apache_beam.transforms.util.BatchElements) (python) ?
My pipeline is generating some batches (PCollection of element type List[T]) and doing some operation on them.
How do I put these back into a PCollection of elements type T?

```
    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as pipeline:
        # prepare themis cleaning output
        data = pipeline | beam.io.ReadFromParquet(file_pattern=input_location)
        output = data | 'Cast' >> beam.ParDo(CastFields(country, slug_name))
        group_batch = output | "Group into batches" >> beam.BatchElements(min_batch_size=500, max_batch_size=10000)
        output = group_batch | 'A costly function, better done in batches' >> beam.ParDo(my_costly_function(country, shared_handle)) # This generates a PCollection of element type List[T]
        # HERE SOME REGROUPING output_regrouped = | 'Some regrouping function' >> outputregroupfunction()
        output_regrouped | 'Write' >> beam.io.WriteToParquet(output_location)
```

The problem is that `WriteToParquet` won't work in batches. it takes PCollection of type T.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BatchElements` creates a `PCollection[List[T]]`. You can apply a [`beam.FlatMap`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/elementwise/flatmap/) to that `PCollection` to get a `PCollection[T]` again.